# Problem displaying list of views when using dictionary as input with SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, list, dictionary, swiftui

I have an array of dictionary which I'm trying to cycle through and use the dictionaries's values as arguments for the views to be displayed. However I get the error:

**Contextual closure type '() -> TrickRowView' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body**

```
let arraySize = begginerTricks.count - 1
ForEach(0...arraySize, id: \.self){
        NavigationLink(
        destination: TrickView(trickId: begginerTricks[$0]["trickId"] as! String),
        label: {
            TrickRowView(name: begginerTricks[$0]["trickName"] as! String, 
                trickType: begginerTricks[$0]["trickType"] as! String, 
                trickComplete: [false,false,false,false], 
                width: width * 0.78, height: height * 0.1)
         })
}
```

However when I use simple values it works fine, for example when I use "name" instead of "begginerTricks[$0]["trickName"]".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not use a struct instead of a dictionary, it would make coding easier and the code easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the compiler is getting confused about the `$0` parameter to your ForEach closure. Try naming that parameter to remove ambiguity over which closure the parameter belongs to:

```
let arraySize = begginerTricks.count - 1
ForEach(0...arraySize, id: \.self){ index in  //Map the parameter to `index`
        NavigationLink(
        destination: TrickView(trickId: begginerTricks[index]["trickId"] as! String),
        label: {
            TrickRowView(name: begginerTricks[index]["trickName"] as! String, 
                trickType: begginerTricks[index]["trickType"] as! String, 
                trickComplete: [false,false,false,false], 
                width: width * 0.78, height: height * 0.1)
         })
}
```